# Fast Permutation with some static elements

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

i have a function which gets a string like "ABA?" the question-mark is a wildcard which can either be A or B the passed string can have multiple wildcards. It should give back multiple strings as an array with all possible solutions. My Code is far to slow. I am new to python so its a little difficult to find a good solution.

When "ABA?" is passed it should return ['ABAA', 'ABAB'].

```
from itertools import product

def possibilities(param):
    result = []
    for i in product([A,B], repeat=param.count('?')):
        string = param
        for p in [i]:
            for val in p:
                string = string.replace('?', str(val), 1)
            result.append(string)
    return result
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, you want to append one per time the letters without repetitions ? So if ABC output : ABCA ABCB ABCC ???Anyway here you can find what are you looking for : https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Comment: there is no C the only letters are AB and a wildcard which can be A or B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1756096/249341) so you can loop over the output. If you have a lot of wildcards, the complete list would require a lot of memory to store completely (it grows exponentially!)

```
import itertools

def possibilties(s):
    n_wildcard = s.count('?')

    for subs in itertools.product(['A','B'], repeat=n_wildcard):
        subs = iter(subs)
        yield ''.join([x if x != '?' else subs.next() for x in s])

for p in possibilties('A?BA?'):
    print p
```

This gives:

```
AABAA
AABAB
ABBAA
ABBAB
```

Comment: Its definitely a better solution but it takes to long to finish it should need to be 10 % faster but i really have no idea how this is achieved.